# How to read any files on "Analyzer with Code Fix" projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-6.0

I am currently trying to create an extension for this using “Visual Studio 2015”.

I want to dynamically retrieve and read some files in a folder in an open solution from the `Analyzer with Code Fix` project. However, `System.IO.StreamReader` referenced in this project did not have an argument constructor that includes a file path. Checked the Object Browser, the assembly file of `System.IO.StreamReader` referenced is `System.IO.dll` in this project.

But, the assembly file I want to reference is `mscorlib.dll`. Also, it was not possible to add a reference `mscorlib.dll`

How can I read files on this project?

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader fs = new System.IO.StreamReader(path)) // error
{
    obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

Comment: What framework are you targeting? How did you try to add the reference to `mscorlib.dll`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The target framework is `.NET Framework 4.5`.An attempt was made to reference `mscorlib.dll` from the reference manager assembly. However, the message says `All Framework assemblies are already referenced.`

Comment: In what code is that exception being thrown and what is the stack trace?

Comment: This error is displayed before compilation. This is because the referenced `System.IO.StreamReader` does not have a constructor whose first argument is `string`.

Comment: `StreamReader` has a constructor with a `string` argument in [.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.5). But not int [.NET Standard 1.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netstandard-1.6)